# StreamingWordCount example maven compile time errors

Tags: maven, streaming, google-bigquery, pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow

I am getting the following errors while running compiling the Google dataflow example on the cloud instance. I am trying to run the streaming example by the name of StreamingWordCount using the following command

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.complete.StreamingWordCount.java
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Google Cloud Dataflow Java Examples - All manual_build
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-source (add-java8-main-source) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all ---
[INFO] Source directory: /home/gaurav_bareja/pipeline/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/src/main/java8 added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-test-source (add-java8-test-source) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-exam
ples-all ---
[INFO] Test Source directory: /home/gaurav_bareja/pipeline/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/src/test/java8 added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/gaurav_bareja/pipeline/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (java8-compile) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) > validate @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) < validate @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.496 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-19T13:23:56+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) on project google-cloud-d
ataflow-java-examples-all: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.
complete.StreamingWordCount.java -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecution
```

Exception

Comment: Could you post a link to the source of the example so that we can reproduce the problem? Also try with `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.complete.StreamingWordCount`  without the `.java` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, that did help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to run the `StreamingWordCount` example that comes with the Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java. The example under that name doesn't exist -- hence, the exception you are seeing.

You likely want to run `WindowedWordCount` instead, an example that shows how to run the same pipeline over either unbounded PCollections in the streaming mode or bounded PCollections in the batch mode.

Please follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples).

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. Also, I had to remove .java from the end.